# ioroutin.c:67:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ' ' is invalid in C99

Tags: c++, c, function, header

I downloaded a code named `ioroutin.c`.
In this code there's a function `get_null_head` and I don't know where it comes form. And I am getting this warning :

> ioroutin.c:67:4: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'get_null_head' is invalid in C99
>         [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                           get_null_head(head);

I seached on google, and we said it comes from a header `ahead.h` but it doesn't work.

What's the problem and how could I remove this warning?

Comment: We don't have remote acccess to your system. So, best guess : it is defined in some other source file. :-)

Comment: Maybe the place where you found this mysterious code could know?

Comment: Well ... at page http://www.geol.lsu.edu/Faculty/Juan/freeware/H/Hermann%202002%20PROGRAMS.330/IRIS/rdseed4.5/Ah/ioroutin.c a file called "ahhead.h" is included. Perhaps you only had a typing error?!?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is: you are missing one library file